# Remote Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have tried **everything** to be able to connect to my MS SQL Server 2012 remotely.
I have read and setup everything like [Kyralessa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5486/kyralessa) wrote in his answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012).

- Enable TCP/IP **done**
- Add 1433 TCP Port **done**
- enable SQL Server Browser **done**
- Add 1433 TCP, 1434 UDP ports to Windows Firewall **done**
- Add sqlserver.exe and sqlbrowser.exe to Windows Firewall **done**
- Use ip address and port to connect **done**

I am still receiving an error message: `Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attampt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time.`

**Nothing works**
Do you maybe have any other solution I could try to solve this problem?

Comment: You granted yourself access to be able to access your own database correct?

Comment: @WhyCry Granted? Where?

Comment: Ignore that previous comment, do you have the error message that appears when you try to connect?

Comment: @WhyCry Yes, I just updated my question with error message.

Comment: You also went to the server properties of your database/server and allowed remote connections?

Comment: I'm heading out for the day, here's a link that I found helpful when I ran into this issue with SQL 2008 and remote connection http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: @WhyCry Yes I did.

Comment: @WhyCry I have already done everything from the link you just posted

Comment: Are you attempting to connect from the same LAN or over the Internet? Have you configured port-forwarding? Can you connect using the `telnet` program? Are you able to access any other server processes running on the same computer (e.g. HTTP on port 80 or Remote Desktop on port 3389)? Are you using a VLAN?

Comment: @Dai currently I am trying to connect to server running on the same PC but using IP address instead of Server Name.
I haven't find anything about Port-Forwarding in any tutorial (for remote access).

Comment: What do you mean by "running on the same PC"? Your question title says "Remote access" - that's completely different.

Comment: @Dai but I am trying to connect via IP Address, doesn't that means I am connecting remotely?

Comment: No, if you were attempting to connect from a physically different computer than that would be "remotely". You're just connecting locally, so the settings you're changing in SQL Server Configuration Manager are inappropriate.

Comment: Give me 20 minutes, I will bring my laptop and will try to connect from that one

Comment: @Dai I just tried to connect with my laptop to my SQL Server using IP address and I am still receiving the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem with Port Forwarding.
I've seen no tutorial for Remote Access to SQL Server with this part.
So, setup 1433 TCP Port forwarding in your Router Settings and everything will work as it should.

Comment: Most database servers aren't behind residential-grade home network routers, that's why ;)

Comment: Well @Dai this is just for testing. I know I will have to improve security a lot if I want this to be a part of my company system (btw, do you have any tips on how to make my application more secure in vb.net/sql server, any links?)

Comment: Respectfully I will not answer that question because it is too broad.